# How to customize WAMPSERVER's Web site for more directories?

Tags: apache, wampserver

In a recent study PHP, I installed WampServer WWW, want to change the default root directory, modify the path of the httpd.conf file in the DocumentRoot file and , but it can not run normally, the web page error: The requested URL /test.php was not found on this server.
PHP/5.6.25 (Win32) Server at localhost Port Apache/2.4.23 80

Comment: Document root is not a file, its a directory.

Comment: DocumentRoot should not be a configuration in the httpd.cnf file?

Comment: You can set up as many sites as you like if you use Virtual Hosts, this is the recommended method in WAMPServer. [See this post for how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)